# Caused by java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

Here's my code and my statement works from SQL Developer but when invoked via an interface as an adapter in a jca file, it returns the **invalid column index** error:

```
<adapter-config name="SelectCCBAPRecordsWithTemplate" adapter="db" wsdlLocation="../WSDLs/SelectCCBAPRecordsWithTemplate.wsdl" xmlns="http://platform.integration.oracle/blocks/adapter/fw/metadata">

  <connection-factory location="eis/DB/CCBPS-CCBDS" UIConnectionName="CCBPS-CCBDS" adapterRef=""/>
  <endpoint-interaction portType="SelectCCBAPRecordsWithTemplate_ptt" operation="SelectCCBAPRecordsWithTemplate">
<interaction-spec className="oracle.tip.adapter.db.DBPureSQLInteractionSpec">
<property name="SqlString" value="SELECT A.AP_REQ_ID,E.GL_ACCT,F.CHAR_VAL,B.SA_ID,B.ADJ_ID,B.CRE_DT,B.ADJ_TYPE_CD,H.CHAR_VAL,FT.GL_DIVISION,G.GL_DIVISION,K.CHAR_VAL,A.ENTITY_NAME,A.COUNTRY,A.ADDRESS1,A.ADDRESS2,A.ADDRESS3,A.ADDRESS4,A.CITY,A.NUM1,A.NUM2,A.COUNTY,A.HOUSE_TYPE,A.STATE,A.POSTAL,B.CURRENCY_CD,A.CURRENCY_PYMNT,A.GEO_CODE,A.IN_CITY_LIMIT,A.PYMNT_METHOD_FLG,B.ADJ_AMT,A.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT,E.FUND_CD, TO_CHAR(NULL) as customRecordElements FROM CI_ADJ_APREQ A, CI_ADJ B,CI_SA C,CI_ADJ_TYPE D,CI_DST_CODE_EFF E,CI_DST_CD_CHAR F,CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR I,CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR K,CI_FT FT,CI_SA_TYPE G,CI_ADJ_TY_CHAR H WHERE A.ADJ_ID = B.ADJ_ID AND B.ADJ_STATUS_FLG ='50' AND A.PYMNT_SEL_STAT_FLG ='N' AND A.BATCH_CD ='APDL' AND A.BATCH_NBR =(select NEXT_BATCH_NBR FROM CI_BATCH_CTRL WHERE BATCH_CD='APDL') AND B.ADJ_ID= FT.SIBLING_ID AND B.SA_ID=C.SA_ID AND B.ADJ_TYPE_CD=D.ADJ_TYPE_CD AND D.DST_ID=E.DST_ID AND E.DST_ID=F.DST_ID AND LTRIM(RTRIM(F.CHAR_TYPE_CD))='TEMPLATE' AND C.CIS_DIVISION = I.CIS_DIVISION AND E.EFFDT=(SELECT MAX (EFFDT) FROM CI_DST_CODE_EFF G WHERE G.DST_ID=E.DST_ID AND G.EFF_STATUS='A' and G.EFFDT&lt;=SYSDATE) AND F.EFFDT=(SELECT MAX (EFFDT) FROM CI_DST_CD_CHAR H WHERE H.DST_ID=F.DST_ID) AND I.EFFDT =(SELECT MAX (EFFDT) FROM CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR J WHERE J.CIS_DIVISION = I.CIS_DIVISION AND J.CHAR_TYPE_CD = I.CHAR_TYPE_CD)  AND C.CIS_DIVISION = K.CIS_DIVISION(+) AND (K.EFFDT is null or (K.EFFDT =(SELECT MAX (EFFDT) FROM CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR L WHERE L.CIS_DIVISION = K.CIS_DIVISION AND L.CHAR_TYPE_CD = K.CHAR_TYPE_CD))) AND G.SA_TYPE_CD = C.SA_TYPE_CD AND G.CIS_DIVISION = C.CIS_DIVISION AND H.ADJ_TYPE_CD = D.ADJ_TYPE_CD AND LTRIM(RTRIM(H.CHAR_TYPE_CD)) = 'VENDORID'"/>
    </interaction-spec>
  </endpoint-interaction>

</adapter-config>
```

The exception is:

> Exception occurred when binding was invoked. Exception occurred during
>   invocation of JCA binding: "JCA Binding execute of Reference operation
>   'SelectCCBAPRecordsWithTemplate' failed due to: Pure SQL
>   Exception.Pure SQL Execute of SELECT .......Caused by
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Here's the updated SQL I used to remove the duplicates:

```
SELECT   
    A.AP_REQ_ID, E.GL_ACCT, B.SA_ID, B.ADJ_ID, B.CRE_DT,
    B.ADJ_TYPE_CD, H.CHAR_VAL, G.GL_DIVISION, A.ENTITY_NAME, 
    A.COUNTRY, A.ADDRESS1, A.ADDRESS2, A.ADDRESS3, A.ADDRESS4,
    A.CITY, A.NUM1, A.NUM2, A.COUNTY, A.HOUSE_TYPE, A.STATE, A.POSTAL,
    B.CURRENCY_CD, A.CURRENCY_PYMNT, A.GEO_CODE, A.IN_CITY_LIMIT,
    A.PYMNT_METHOD_FLG, B.ADJ_AMT, A.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT, E.FUND_CD, 
    TO_CHAR(NULL) AS customRecordElements 
FROM 
    CISADM.CI_ADJ_APREQ A, CISADM.CI_ADJ B, CISADM.CI_SA C,
    CISADM.CI_ADJ_TYPE D, CISADM.CI_DST_CODE_EFF E ,CISADM.CI_DST_CD_CHAR F,
    CISADM.CI_SA_TYPE G, CISADM.CI_ADJ_TY_CHAR H 
WHERE 
    A.ADJ_ID = B.ADJ_ID 
    AND B.ADJ_STATUS_FLG = '50' 
    AND A.PYMNT_SEL_STAT_FLG = 'N' 
    AND A.BATCH_CD = 'APDL' 
    AND A.BATCH_NBR = (SELECT NEXT_BATCH_NBR 
                       FROM CISADM.CI_BATCH_CTRL 
                       WHERE BATCH_CD = 'APDL') 
    AND B.SA_ID = C.SA_ID 
    AND B.ADJ_TYPE_CD = D.ADJ_TYPE_CD 
    AND D.DST_ID = E.DST_ID 
    AND E.DST_ID = F.DST_ID 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(F.CHAR_TYPE_CD)) = 'TEMPLATE' 
    AND E.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX (EFFDT) FROM CISADM.CI_DST_CODE_EFF I 
                   WHERE I.DST_ID = E.DST_ID 
                     AND I.EFF_STATUS = 'A' 
                     AND I.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
    AND F.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX (EFFDT) FROM CISADM.CI_DST_CD_CHAR J 
                   WHERE J.DST_ID = F.DST_ID) 
    AND G.SA_TYPE_CD = C.SA_TYPE_CD 
    AND G.CIS_DIVISION = C.CIS_DIVISION 
    AND H.ADJ_TYPE_CD = D.ADJ_TYPE_CD 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(H.CHAR_TYPE_CD)) = 'VENDORID'
```

Final Edit: In my BPEL process, there was a variable that I had defined that I later decided not to use. Even though I removed all references to where I passed a value to it, I forgot to remove the declaration of the variable itself. I didn't think it would cause an issue with the SQL itself, especially since it was only a declaration but as soon as I removed it, the code started working. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Can you share the exception's exact message?

Comment: This is what it says: Exception occurred when binding was invoked.
Exception occurred during invocation of JCA binding: "JCA Binding execute of Reference operation 'SelectCCBAPRecordsWithTemplate' failed due to: Pure SQL Exception.Pure SQL Execute of SELECT .......Caused by java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of reformatting you query to see better. **It has 33 columns**. This means you can retrieve values using indexes ranging from `1` to `33`. For example:

- `rs.getString(1)` will work.
- `rs.getString(33)` will work.
- `rs.getString(34)` will NOT work. Exceeds 33 columns.

Your query:

```
SELECT A.AP_REQ_ID, -- 1st column
E.GL_ACCT,
F.CHAR_VAL,
B.SA_ID,
B.ADJ_ID,
B.CRE_DT,
B.ADJ_TYPE_CD,
H.CHAR_VAL,
FT.GL_DIVISION,
G.GL_DIVISION, -- 10th column
K.CHAR_VAL,
A.ENTITY_NAME,
A.COUNTRY,
A.ADDRESS1,
A.ADDRESS2,
A.ADDRESS3,
A.ADDRESS4,
A.CITY,
A.NUM1,
A.NUM2, -- 20th column
A.COUNTY,
A.HOUSE_TYPE,
A.STATE,
A.POSTAL,
B.CURRENCY_CD,
A.CURRENCY_PYMNT,
A.GEO_CODE,
A.IN_CITY_LIMIT,
A.PYMNT_METHOD_FLG,
B.ADJ_AMT, -- 30
A.SCHEDULED_PAY_DT,
E.FUND_CD,
TO_CHAR(NULL) as customRecordElements -- 33rd column
FROM CI_ADJ_APREQ A,
CI_ADJ B,
CI_SA C,
CI_ADJ_TYPE D,
CI_DST_CODE_EFF E,
CI_DST_CD_CHAR F,
CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR I,
CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR K,
CI_FT FT,
CI_SA_TYPE G,
CI_ADJ_TY_CHAR H
WHERE A.ADJ_ID = B.ADJ_ID
AND B.ADJ_STATUS_FLG ='50'
AND A.PYMNT_SEL_STAT_FLG ='N'
AND A.BATCH_CD ='APDL'
AND A.BATCH_NBR =
(
  select NEXT_BATCH_NBR
  FROM CI_BATCH_CTRL
  WHERE BATCH_CD='APDL'
)
AND B.ADJ_ID= FT.SIBLING_ID
AND B.SA_ID=C.SA_ID
AND B.ADJ_TYPE_CD=D.ADJ_TYPE_CD
AND D.DST_ID=E.DST_ID
AND E.DST_ID=F.DST_ID
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(F.CHAR_TYPE_CD))='TEMPLATE'
AND C.CIS_DIVISION = I.CIS_DIVISION
AND E.EFFDT=
(
  SELECT MAX (EFFDT)
  FROM CI_DST_CODE_EFF G
  WHERE G.DST_ID=E.DST_ID
  AND G.EFF_STATUS='A'
  and G.EFFDT&lt
  ;
  =SYSDATE
)
AND F.EFFDT=(SELECT MAX (EFFDT) FROM CI_DST_CD_CHAR H WHERE H.DST_ID=F.DST_ID)
AND I.EFFDT =
(
  SELECT MAX (EFFDT)
  FROM CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR J
  WHERE J.CIS_DIVISION = I.CIS_DIVISION
  AND J.CHAR_TYPE_CD = I.CHAR_TYPE_CD
)
AND C.CIS_DIVISION = K.CIS_DIVISION(+)
AND
(
  K.EFFDT is null
  or
  (
    K.EFFDT =
    (
      SELECT MAX (EFFDT)
      FROM CI_CIS_DIV_CHAR L
      WHERE L.CIS_DIVISION = K.CIS_DIVISION
      AND L.CHAR_TYPE_CD = K.CHAR_TYPE_CD
    )
  )
)
AND G.SA_TYPE_CD = C.SA_TYPE_CD
AND G.CIS_DIVISION = C.CIS_DIVISION
AND H.ADJ_TYPE_CD = D.ADJ_TYPE_CD
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(H.CHAR_TYPE_CD)) = 'VENDORID'
```

Comment: Correct, in order to not run into those sort of issues, I use them by name rather than index, as an example:      <ns1:A.AP_REQ_ID xml:id="id_90">
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:A.AP_REQ_ID" xml:id="id_91"/>
          </ns1:A.AP_REQ_ID>

Comment: Well... you have duplicate names: `CHAR_VAL` is one of them. The client will be confused which one is which.

Comment: Thanks but I tried running it without the 2 char_vals and only kept the H.Char_val and I still got the exact same error.

Comment: Not to look snooty but `GL_DIVISION` is also duplicate. Just trying to help. You can still have those columns if you use an alias, as in `H.CHAR_VAL as CHAR_VAL2`

Comment: Here's what I ran, still with the same issue and thanks for your help. I've been at it all day and I am at a complete loss: Oops it's too long.

Comment: I updated the question with the new SQL i ran with the exact same error.